# Remove Turn Editing on for courses in Moodle/Totara

Tags: moodle, totara

I have a bunch of custom user groups.  I need to change the permissions for one of the user groups so they don't see "Turn editing on" button or link.  I figured out a way to do this in a reports section.  I can't figure out a way to do this for course section.

I deactivated manage blocks and manage activities and that removed the button on all of the sections except courses.  I tried to deactivate update course and a bunch other course related capabilities with no luck.  Did not see any sort of manage courses capability.

Any help would be appreciated as I just inherited this site and have had no previous experience with Moodle.

[image]

Totara version 2.7
Moodle version 2.2.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to this by code or configuration? If you want to do this, simply by configuration, just make a new user group for them "Site administration->User->Permissions->Define Roles", give them the ones you want them to have. Then assign the users in question this role. They should not see the buttons in question.